# Responsive div height - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive

Can anyone help me to find out what I'm doing wrong please?
Click on the link to view the website with the problem please - [click here](http://veronikalesnakova.co.uk/trouble-website/)

I cannot make green box responsive in height. It is scaling in width however height stays the same. I would like to have it resized together so the green box resizes in height and width at the same time and fits the screen.

Any help would be appreciated as I really do not know what could be possibly wrong there.

Thank you

Comment: The height is also getting adjusted as per the width of the screen. Tried the page on the device as it is responsive.

Comment: Hi Nitesh, 
Thank you for your reply! When you open it on mobile or tablet, it is responsive. 
However, what the client wants is not having to scroll down to see full contact form when you open it on different laptop/desktop screen, the position is 'fixed' and the green box resize with the screen to fit the screen (if that makes any sense?) At the moment, you have to scroll down little bit to be able to see the green box with contact form.

Comment: I am sorry, but I need not scroll down to view the contact form. However, you can try minimizing the padding 140px which is at the top of the page.

Comment: So on your device (what screen resolution it is please?) you can see full contact form in green box without having to scroll down? 
I tried to minimize the padding on top of the page but the problem with that is that on bigger screens (1200px bigger), the green box is not in the middle of the screen (this is the reason why there is 140px padding on top of the page). 
Do you have any ideas/suggestions how this could be resolved? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the height to auto/100%.

or

This may not be what you are looking for but I had a similar problem and media queries helped me solve it.

You set a min-width and depending on that you set the heigth of the div.

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
         .loginbox
         {
          height: 120px; / height: 50%;
         }
     }
```

You can refer to W3schools for media queries

[Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You might try relative to a view point rule in Bootstrap:
[Relative to view point](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-viewport) . It makes a rule where your div 100% of your screen independantly of your device. Here is an example: 
 
`<div class="min-vw-100">Min-width 100vw</div><div class="min-vh-100">Min-height 100vh</div><div class="vw-100">Width 100vw</div><div class="vh-100">Height 100vh</div>`